# How do you pass parameters to a BootstrapperFile?

Tags: .net, wix, installation, windows-installer, bootstrapper

My bootstrapper, `setup.exe` is generated as follows (excerpt is from my `.wixproj` file):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
    <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.VSTORuntime.4.0">
      <ProductName>Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperFile>
  </ItemGroup>
  </BootstrapperFile>
  <GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="My Application" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" CopyComponents="False" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\BootStrapper" ApplicationRequiresElevation="True" Culture="en-US" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' " />
</Target>
```

`msiexec` supports `/norestart`, and I want to pass this `/norestart` parameter into these prerequisites, like the Tools for Office Runtime and .NET 3.5 installers. I have no clue how to pass command line arguments to these MSI's that the bootstrapper will download and install. Is there any standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default bootstrapper this is how we pass the arguments from command line:

```
<Wix>
  <Bundle> 
    <Variable Name="CommandLineArgument" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage>
        <MsiProperty Name="CommandLineArgument" Value="[CommandLineArgument]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Make a note of the BAL:Overridable. That's how I was able to make sure that we can pass the property value from command line. Make sure you add the namespace declaration to the Wix element xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension", and link to the WixBalExtension.dll.

Comment: While that is great for the WiX bootstrapper, I am using the Microsoft Windows bootstrapper generator inside of my actual .wixproj file to generate it with the code above, so I'm just wondering if I can pass any parameters to the MSI's that the Microsoft bootstrapper uses.

Comment: @Alexandru The confusion arises because you tagged your question with [wix].

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes, because it is a part of my WiX installer's post-build setting. I had no intention of creating any confusion. I have also tagged "bootstrapper", but either way, you can see from the XAML that I'm not using the WiX bootstrapper project, but my WiX project has a post-build invocation of the Microsoft bootstrapper.

Comment: I read the question and assumed it to be Wix bootstrapper, my bad.

Comment: I had to create a WiX bootstrapped to do this in the end, since the generic Windows bootstrapped can't.